# Capturar valores de depois de um input checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Bom dia, eu possuo um formulário de 'Atendimentos' em que há um checkbox para cada serviço.

[image: Segue imagem]

Atualmente eu consigo pegar o id de cada checkbox selecionado, colocar em um array e imprimir esse array, porém não é esse meu objetivo. Eu gostaria de que para cada checkbox selecionado, capturar o valor do serviço e incrementasse no input 'Total'.

Meu código de formulário está assim:

```
                    <?php  foreach($servicos as  $servico): ?>

                        <label class="checkbox-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="servico[]"  value="<?=$servico['id']?>">
                            <?=$servico['descricao'] .' R$ ' . number_format($servico['valor'],2,',','.'); ?></label>

                        </br>
                    <?php endforeach?>

                    <h2>Total</h2>
                    <input type="number" name="totalValor" disabled>
```

E meu codigo para captura de id dos checkbox está assim:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ids = []

    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            ids.push($(this).val());
            $("#idServicos").text(ids);
            alert(ids);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        var total = $(":checkbox:checked").get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
            return tot + Number(el.value);
        }, 0);
        $('[name="totalValor"]').val(total);
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/vc6m4wvt/

Dessa maneira com `$(":checkbox:checked")` vais buscar os `checkbox` selecionados (podes adaptar este seletor melhor mas sem ver o teu HTML deixo ficar assim), depois convertes numa array nativa com `.get()` e usas o método `.reduce()` para somar tudo. Desta maneira não inporta quandos elementos tens. Uso o `Number()` para converter o `.value` que retorna uma *String* em Tipo: *Numero* para poder fazer a adição.

---

Para guardares ambos o ID (que é o value do input) e também o `$servico['valor']` podes colocá-lo num campo `data-` assim:

```
<?php  foreach($servicos as  $servico): ?>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="servico[]"  data-valor="<?=$servico['valor']?>" value="<?=$servico['id']?>">
        <?=$servico['descricao'] .' R$ ' . number_format($servico['valor'],2,',','.'); ?></label>
```

e depois ler isso no JavaScript muda 1 linha em relação ao código que coloquei em cima,  assim:

```
 return tot + Number(el.dataset.valor);
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vc6m4wvt/2/

Comment: Perfeito Sergio, funcionou aqui. Muito obrigado pela atenção e me desculpe por te perturbar tanto. =D

Answer (score 2):

No `onchange` você devia percorrer todos `<inputs type="checkbox">` que estiverem `checked` e incrementar o seu valor ao total. [EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/jnp655sy/3/)

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   var total = 0;
   var servicos = '';
   $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
      servicos += $(this).data('servico')+ '<br>';
   });
   $('input[name="totalValor"]').val(total);
   $('.servicos').html(servicos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="140" data-servico="dentista">140<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="130" data-servico="cardiologista">130<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="70" data-servico="oftalmologista">70<br>
<input name="totalValor" type="number">
<div class="servicos">
  
</div>
```

Comment: isso poderia fazer para checkbox com names diferentes ?

Comment: Sim, podes dar a mesma classe às checkboxes que queres calcular e só tens de alterar para `$('input.minha-class').on('change', function() {` . Mas nem precisas, não estás dependente do `name` aqui, apenas deves ter a certeza que não tens mais chekboxes sem ser as que queres calcular. esta linha `$('input[name="totalValor"]')` é apenas o input onde vai ser apresentado o total

Comment: poderia responder essa minha pergunta por gentileza http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178790/como-enviar-checkbox-com-names-diferentes-para-o-mysql